# How to modify data retrieved from select in sql?

Tags: sql

suppose i am having some unwanted characters in the data present in a column for eg name column in customers table has data like < ,is there anyway to modify such characters like '<' to blankspace while retrieving this data using select statement? This is to prevent xss scripts showing up due to old data which is having such unwanted characters

e.g:

```
select * 
from customers
```

returns

```
Id   Name      Age  city                    salary
--  ------     ---  ----                    ------
1   <hari      32   Ahmedabad               4000
2   Khilan     25   Delhi                   5678
3   kaushik    23   Kota                    234
```

i want `<hari` to be displayed as `hari` when this data is retrieved using select statement.How to achieve this ?

Comment: do you want to only replace special symbol & space. Am i Right?

Answer (score 2):

Something like...

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(a.name,'<', ''), '>','') 
FROM ...
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be better to write a function to remove special characters. Here the function replaces any character that does not look like `a-z,A-Z(if case sensitive),0-9 and Space`. You can add more if needed. 
For example if you want to retain period(.) the use `'[^a-zA-Z0-9 .]'`

**Function:**

```
CREATE FUNCTION ufn_RemoveSpecialCharacters
(
@String VARCHAR(500),
@Exclude VARCHAR(100),
@CollapseSpaces BIT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(500)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @StartString INT,
    @EndString INT,
    @FinalString VARCHAR(500),
    @CurrentString CHAR(1),
    @PreviousString CHAR(1)

    SET @StartString = 1
    SET @EndString = LEN(ISNULL(@String, ''))

    WHILE @StartString <= @EndString
       BEGIN
          SET @CurrentString = SUBSTRING(@String, @StartString, 1)
          SET @PreviousString = SUBSTRING(@String, @StartString-1, 1)

          IF @CurrentString LIKE ISNULL(@Exclude,'[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]')
             BEGIN
                SET @CurrentString = ''
                IF @CollapseSpaces = 1
                SET @FinalString = CASE WHEN @PreviousString = CHAR(32) THEN ISNULL(@FinalString, '') ELSE ISNULL(@FinalString, '')+' ' END
             END
          ELSE
             BEGIN
                SET @FinalString = ISNULL(@FinalString, '') + @CurrentString

                IF @CollapseSpaces = 1
                BEGIN
                    SET @FinalString = REPLACE(@FinalString,'  ',' ')
                END
             END
          SET @StartString = @StartString + 1
       END

    --PRINT @String
    RETURN LTRIM(RTRIM(@FinalString))

END
GO
```

**Usage:**

Does not collapse Spaces

```
SELECT dbo.ufn_RemoveSpecialCharacters('This #$%string has#$% special #$% characters     and spaces))', '[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]', 0)
```

Collapses multiple Spaces

```
SELECT dbo.ufn_RemoveSpecialCharacters('This #$%string has#$% special #$% characters     and spaces))', '[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]', 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example

SELECT Replace(Column Name, ' ', '') AS C

FROM Contacts

WHERE Replace(Column Name, ' ', '') LIKE 'whatever'

Hope this was helpful